# Case Statement - using BETWEEN. Ms Access to SQL Server

Tags: c#, ms-access, switch-statement, subquery

Hi have made a query in ms access, as my DB is access, however i am creating reports in C# RDLC.

Im just going through making my dataadapters for the reports and i just can't get this CASE statement and BETWEEN to work!!

Now funnily it does actually produce the correct data.. but i get an error:

> Error in list of function arguments: 'BETWEEN' not recognized.
>   Unable to parse query text.

```
SELECT        [CountAge].AgeGroup, COUNT(*) AS CountOfAgeGroup
FROM
(SELECT Switch([Age] BETWEEN 0 AND 17, '0-17',
 [Age] BETWEEN 18 AND 30, '18-30', 
[Age] BETWEEN 30 AND 45, '30-45', 
[Age] BETWEEN 45 AND 60, '45-60', 
[Age] > 60, 'Over 60') AS AgeGroup

FROM
(SELECT tblcustomers.firstname, tblcustomers.lastname, Year(Now()) - 
Year([DOB])  AS Age FROM TblCustomers )) as CountAge


GROUP BY [CountAge].AgeGroup
```

I've tried a number of things but i cant seem to get it right! Any advice would be great.

It also has an error with Year(date) and changes to year but it works when i change it back.

**Update - Clarification (because I'm stupidly vague - sorry)**

---

So just clarifying my problem.
My DB is in access - not sql server - that was a bad tag of mine.

I have created the query inside Access and it works, exactly as it is above.
HOWEVER I'm trying to create it as a datatable for a report in Visual Studio as an RDLC report.

In Dataset Designer I am adding a datatable usign the above query however it doesnt work due to the aforementioned error (BETWEEN).

I have since tried Gustav's suggestion in replacing BETWEEN with > and >= etc however i now get this error;

> Error in list of function arguments: '<' not recognized.
>   Unable to parse query text.

**Update 2: THIS QUERY WORKS.. as in it DOES create results that are correct,** however because of this Unable to Parse Query Error.. i cant actually SAVE it.
Ideas?

Comment: So what have you tried? What is the connection string?

Comment: So are you using sql server or not? You have it tagged and mentioned in your question title but the explanation of the question makes it sound like everything is in Access and nothing at all to do with sql server.

Comment: Did you know that CASE is an expression, and not a statement? I did, because people love to tell people that call it a case statement...and now I am one of them.

Comment: I removed the `sql-server` tag, this is a tag you should use if you are using Microsoft Sql Server. Everything in your question is specific to MS Access. If there is something relating to Sql Server you can re-tag it but update your question with the specifics for Sql Server.

Comment: Yeh sorry about the sqlserver tag, i must have typed sql and selected by server by access.  I was referring to the SQL text for msaccess! Sorry!

Comment: @Leonidas199x, respectfully, it sounds like you know the answer and obviously I'm doing this wrong, but I still can't figure it out. Would you mind expanding on this?  Or are you literally just having a go at the title?

Comment: Well I've spent 2 hours trying to work this out... and just can't get it so if anyone does have ideas I'm happy to try.

Comment: @GlennAngel afraid not, I came when you had tagged it as SQL server, no idea about access, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Switch* function doesn't take SQL syntax. So:

```
Switch([Age] <= 17, '0-17',
    [Age] <= 30, '18-30', 
    [Age] <= 45, '30-45', 
    [Age] <= 60, '45-60', 
    [Age] > 60, 'Over 60')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select case when [Age] between 0 and 17 then '0-17' 
           when [Age] between 18 and 30 then '18-30' 
           when [Age] between 31 and 45 then '31-30' 
           when [Age] between 46 and 60 then '46-60' 
           when [Age] >60 then '>60'
            else 'Invalid Age' end 
    from (SELECT tblcustomers.firstname, tblcustomers.lastname, Year(Now())  
    Year([DOB])  AS Age FROM TblCustomers) as CountAge
```

Else Case is for when wrong data entered in Database like future date.
User defined function is most suitable solution in current scenario as per usability and maintainability.